# Continuous without auxiliary verb: "code running/loading"

Tags: gerunds

When i dial ussd code on my phone or open a game, it says "Ussd code running" or "loading". As i know without verb words are just phrase and phrase doesn't perform action. But here "loading" and "Ussd code running" look progressive/continuous tense without auxiliary verb, am i right?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it means "USSD code *is* running," but this kind of abbreviated language is common where space is at a premium --- headlines, instruction manuals, signs, and as here, messages on electronic equipment.

Comment: Similar abbreviated language generated by software includes: “Game loading...”, “Initializing updates...”, “Loading data...” or the old classic “Reticulating splines...” (the last one is a joke and is intentionally meaningless).